# Given ifconfig RX/TX transmited packets, how can I obtain RX/TX transmited bytes?

Tags: networking

I am running Ubuntu **Linux** v18, and this is the info that `ifconfig` yields about my NIC:

```
$ ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.123  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::4a75:bbe4:742d:d77b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:55:c7:9f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2443063  bytes 868405621 (828.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2343559  bytes 1022562153 (975.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Some systems (i.e: embedded Linux on routers) **only report RX/TX packets**, but do not show RX/TX bytes.

Is there any way on Linux operating systems to **obtain RX/TX bytes given RX/TX packets**?

I think some correlated questions would be:

- Is this equivalence always the same (i.e: 1024 factor) ?
- Does this equivalence changes while running (dynamic) ?
- Is this equivalence operating system dependent? Or maybe NIC dependent?
- Is there any equivalence at all?

Comment: No, you can only guestimate bytes from packets. Try `ip -s link show eth0`, maybe it works on your router (it does on mine ;-)).

Comment: Also, `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes`, `(cd /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics; grep . rx_bytes tx_bytes)`

Answer (score 1):

There’s no equivalence, packets vary in size depending on their contents. You can only get minimum and maximum sizes; for example, Ethernet frames can occupy between 72 and 1530 octets (ignoring jumbo frames), so *n* packets on an Ethernet interface represent somewhere between 72 × *n* and 1530 × *n* transmitted bytes.

The `ifconfig` command on your router might not show the byte counts, but if your router runs Linux, those counts are tracked; as [mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308316/mosvy) commented, you should be able to see them using

```
ip -s link show eth0
```

or

```
head /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/*_bytes
```

Comment: The questioner is also erroneously ascribing a difference caused by the use of different `ifconfig` comands to a difference in Linux.